# Call dll which is in folder other than system32

Tags: shortcut, rundll32

I want to call my dll through a shortcut, but I need to identify the current directory the dll is in.

At the moment I can only call it this way:
C:\Windows\System32\rundll32.exe C:\Users\Public\BUS.dll, print

And I would like to call her that:
C:\Windows\System32\rundll32.exe BUS.dll, print

I need a command that returns the current directory and calls the dll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your current directory is the one where `bus.dll` resides, you can modify the command as follows:

```
C:\Windows\System32\rundll32.exe %cd%\BUS.dll
```

`%cd%` is the Windows cmd variable for the current directory ([Reference](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-variables.html)).